# Converting UIImage into const char*?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, protocol-buffers

I need to convert a `UIImage` into `const char *` because I am using `protobuffer` from google and structure of message accepts this type of parameter. I started with parsing the image into `NSData`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sign_up_button"];
NSData *imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);  
const char *test = (const char*)[bytesString bytes];
```

But when I print the result this is what i get:`\xff\xd8\xff\xe0` what is wrong because the result must be a long string with encoded characters.

Comment: You see the escaped characters because they fall outside of the printable character range. The string `test` contains the PNG representation of the image in binary form.

Comment: If you need a 0-terminated string of printable characters, you can base64-encode your data

Comment: @user1781290 How can use base64-encode I know this return `NSString`, from this to make another convert into const char*?

Comment: @user1781290 I do not think that he can choose the format.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Maybe I do not know protobuffer, it was only a suggestion. geonl Look into NSData if you want to use base64 encodings

Comment: This was no critic to your suggestion. I just wanted to say that this will not solve the whole problem.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad No offense taken

Answer (score 3):

"Printing" `char*` aborts, when \0 is reached. This is a possible content of image data. You cannot "print" it. You cannot handle the data as a C-string at all, because C-strings are 0-terminated. Do not use any function that expects a C-string. It will fail.

Store a length instead and handle it as "byte data".

Comment: True, though he can print each char in a `for` loop since he knows the length of the array. For debugging purposes i mean.

Comment: Or he can use `– initWithBytes:length:encoding:` et al., because they take a length parameter. (`NSString` stores the raw data *not* 0-terminated but length-based.)

Comment: ok, I understand now, it's more clear. I start to make debug because the image what arrived on the server is corrupted and can't be opened.

Comment: You should really pass the "string" (it's a byte array) as raw as possible. For debugging purpose follow user1781290's hint.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I tried with `– initWithBytes:length:encoding:` but the result was nil, this was a big mystery for me.

Comment: `NSString *stringBytes =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:imageData.bytes length:imageData.length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *test = [stringBytes UTF8String];`

Comment: NSASCIIStringEncoding is a problem, because the data will contain bytes outside ASCII (which is 7 bit only).

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Ok, for me this thinks are a little stranger. I tested also `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but still the result is `nill`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Not every byte combination is valid UTF8. Try to use user1781290's suggestion for debugging (base64 encoding).

Comment: ok, I will make a shot with this, but I don't put to many hopes in this bullet (debugging).Thanks